# Warped AdS geometry

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am having difficulty of finding more basic information on warped geometries. All the standard textbooks are not covering it.

In the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warped_geometry) it's only said that warped geometry is the one which can be decomposed in a certain way, but there are no details. All the articles mentioning warped AdS geometry refers to topological massive gravity.

If someone can tell me where I could find some introduction to warped geometries and it's uses, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many sources of info about AdS geometries on the net.  I think the simplest introduction to these models is:
http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/MaximeGabella/rs.pdf
This covers the Randall-Sundrum model, you can also check the original paper:
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221

The texts above address AdS geometry in extra dimensional models.  The paper below addresses extra dimensions in general and also talks about the AdS extra dimensions:
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0404096

Is this what you had in mind?
There is a lot more material to be found on the arxiv if you search it from spires (www.inspirehep.net).

Comment: The firs link is forbidden, but I think that the TASI lectures will do. I need a definition what is warped AdS (AdS_3 to be exact), a bit about the symmetries (altho that follows from the symmetries of the AdS_3). The general info.